# Vue & webpack & typescript "Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization"

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack

```js
// webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const LicenseWebpackPlugin = require("license-webpack-plugin").LicenseWebpackPlugin;
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');

module.exports = (env, { mode }) => ({
  entry: './src/main.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      }, {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader?url=false', 'sass-loader']
      }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.vue', '.ts', '.js' ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static'),
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: 'index.css' }),
    new LicenseWebpackPlugin({
      outputFilename: 'licenses.txt'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.DEVELOPMENT': `${mode === "development"}`
    }),
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
  ],
  watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 200,
    poll: 1000
  }
});
```

```
// main.ts
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
console.log(App);
```

```
<template>
    <div>
        HI
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
    components: {}
});
</script>

<style lang="sass">
</style>
```

I use webpack to compile vue & typescript code. Webpack compiles all code without any errors, but in runtime, something in `App.vue` makes error.

If I add `lang="ts"` attribute to script tag in my single file component, it makes error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization`. Without that option, it works well.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just bumped into the same problem and, after hours of Googling, I finally found the solution in a [corner](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#webpack-configuration) of Vue documentations.

Basically, you need to add an extra `appendTsSuffixTo` option to your webpack configuration.

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
          appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
      }
```